# Javascript: How to set style of child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of divs that are nested inside a parent div. There is a function when I click a custom button on a google map it slides one the divs to the right and slides in another div on its left. What this does though is moves the buttons off screen and out of focus where you can access them that are in the bottom right of the screen. What I tried to do to combat this is the following. Set negative margins to pull those divs back into focus but it is not working.

```
document.getElementById('alert-list').style.width = "403px";
document.getElementById('map-wrapper').style.marginLeft = "403px";
document.getElementById('mapBtns').style.marginLeft = "-403px";
document.getElementById('mapAds').style.marginLeft = "-205px";
```

"alert-list" is the div that slides in from the left. "map-wrapper" is slid to the right 403px as shown above as to make room for the div sliding in on the left (alert-list). All this works great when the page loads or you hit the button on the map. My issue is "mapBtns" "mapAds" which is nested inside of "map-wrapper". I started troubleshooting this and discovered while all of them are nested inside a div call "container".  "mapBtns" "mapAds" is nested inside of "map-wrapper. Now what is strange is when I view the elements in console I can see the styles from the javascript function is being applied to those divs as I see it inline but, "mapBtns" "mapAds" are not responding to those styling changes on screen.

Is there something else I need to do to apply these styles that I am missing or not doing correctly? Here is the full function.

```
function openAlerts() {
    document.getElementById('alert-list').style.width = "403px";
    document.getElementById('map-wrapper').style.marginLeft = "403px";
    document.getElementById('mapBtns').style.marginRight = "-403px";
    document.getElementById('mapAds').style.marginRight = "-205px";
}
```

**EDIT**

After some further investigation and troubleshooting I think I have narrowed down where the conflict is coming from. Just not sure how to resolve it as I am not expireanced enough with javascript. In my Google Maps code I have the following that places the buttons on the map. Which overrides any CSS defined by "mapBtns". I am just not sure how to override that.

```
// Load the map fullscreen collapse top button   
   var fullScreen = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(fullscreen);

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {$('#fullscreen').delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");});

   // Load the map control buttons     
    var mapControl = document.getElementById('controls');
         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(mapControl);

         google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {$('#controls').delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");});
```

Comment: that's pure js, not jquery involved - you don't need that tag

Comment: Post your HTML please

Comment: @Gonzalo.- It still might mean he is willing to accept a jquery answer